# Cómo impedir que javascript aproxime un número que tenga un decimal .5?

Tags: javascript

```js
function cuartiles(){
 let lista=[34,28,20,17,44,54,94,84,23,13,15,66,19];
 let contarE= lista.length;
 let Qi=4;
 let operacion= contarE+1;
 operacion=operacion*Qi;
 operacion=operacion/4;
 lista.sort(function(a,b){
  return a-b;
 });
 let posicion = resultado2.toString().indexOf('.5');

console.log(posicion);
 let resultado1=lista[operacion-1];
 let resultado2=lista[operacion-2];
 let resultado3= resultado1+resultado2;
 resultado3= resultado3/2;
 alert("Lista de menor a mayor"+" "+lista+'            '+
  'Este es el resultado:'+" "+operacion+"                    "+ 
  " la cantidad de meses es:"+resultado3);
 alert(resultado1);

}
```

estoy intentando hacer un proyecto pero tengo la siguiente duda: como evitar que `JavaScript` aproxime al valor más cercano usando la función `Math.round()`.

Quiero que aproxime al siguiente entero pero que no aproxime cuando el resultado sea un número como **10.5**, **9.5**,**2.5**,**4.5** etc, me imagino que se utilizaría:

```js
function cuartiles(){
 let lista=[13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 23, 28, 34, 44, 54, 66, 84, 94];
let Qi=3;
let cuenta=lista.length;
let resultado= cuenta+1;
let resultado2= resultado*Qi/4;

if (resultado2==no sé que poner acá para que decirle que cuando el resultado contenga un.5 no lo iguale.) {
 document.write(resultado2);
}else{
 alert(Math.round(resultado2));
}
 
}
```

Comment: ¿Entonces que solo aproxime cuando el decimal sea a partir del .6?

Comment: Osea, cuando por ejemplo valga 3.334 que lo aproxime a 3 y cuando sea por ejemplo 3.578 que lo aproxime a 4 o cuando sea 3.6 a 4, la cosa es que no aproxime cuando de 3.5 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se como se haria con un valor numerico, pero podrias intentar convertir el entero a string y asi verificar si existe `.5` en la cadena con la funcion `indexOf` que te devuelve la posicion en que se encuentra la parte a buscar o te devuelve un -1 si no se encontro la parte, entonces podrias intentar:

```
function cuartiles(){
    let lista=[13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 23, 28, 34, 44, 54, 66, 84, 94];
let Qi=3;
let cuenta=lista.length;
let resultado= cuenta+1;
let resultado2= resultado*Qi/4;

let posicion = resultado2.toString().indexOf('.5')

console.log(posicion)
if (posicion != -1) {
    document.write(resultado2);
}else{
    alert(Math.round(resultado2));
}

}
```

Comment: No entiendo como funcionaria, verás lo que necesito es crear un if para cuando aparezca un .5, en este se utilizará la variable resultado1, resultado2 y resultado3, imprimiendo resultado3 y else{que simplemente muestre el resultado1.